# Exactly what part of SIDH is proven to be NP-hard?

Tags: elliptic-curves, post-quantum-cryptography, isogeny

SIDH is quantum secure, why is it quantum secure? Exactly which part of the algorithm is proven to be NP-hard? Computing the isogeny function?

Comment: Secure against quantom computer does not imply NP hard.

Comment: @MeirMaor Understood, I meant that SIDH is quantum secure because it’s been proven to be NP-hard, but nowhere can I find that paper.

Comment: I don't know of any part of SIDH which has been shown to be NP-hard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SIDH is believed to be quantum secure because the fastest known quantum attacks against it (which is based on [claw finding algorithm](http://arxiv.org/abs/0708.2584)) require exponential time with complexity $\mathcal{O}(p^{1/6})$.

Comment: Is SIDH in itself proven quantum hard (regardless of any attacks planned against it?)

Comment: @edlothia No, it is not proven quantum-hard, only believed to be so because no quantum attacks are known, just like factoring et al. are believed to be classical-hard because no classical attacks are known.